# Passing a listbox from page1.aspx to page2.aspx

Tags: c#

I have tried several suggestions from this forum to no avail re the above.

I get the error code:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

and the line of code it highlights is:

```
MessageLabel2.Text = "Your 1st prod " + myList[0] + myList[1] + ".";
```

My setup is as follows.
Page1 has Listbox1 and I can see it contains what I want to pass to page2.
Button1 on page1 does a PostBackUrl="Page2.aspx"/> when clicked

Page1 code behind does:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   public static List<string> myList = new List<string>();

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //TRANSFER TO THE NEXT WEB PAGE 

        for (int i = 0; i < ListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            myList.Add(ListBox1.Items[i].ToString());
        Session["Finallist"] = myList;
        //Response.Redirect("Page2.aspx");
```

Page2 also has a Listbox2 and a MessageLabel2 and I use MessageLabel2 to simply display messages like "You are in Page2 " (and others) on Page_load.
Page 2 code behind is:

```
public partial class Page2 : BasePage
    {
        public static List<string> myList = new List<string>();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            MessageLabel2.Text = "You are in Page2 ";
             myList = (List<string>)Session["Finallist"];

     MessageLabel2.Text = "Your 1st prod " + myList[0] + myList[1] + ".";
```

Additionally I even thought that giving page1 a Form Id="Form1" and page2 a Form Id="Form2" would enable me to do something like Form2.Listbox2 = Form1.Listbox1 , but that doesnt cut it either.
You will see by the commented out code I have tried several workarounds.
Any help/ideas greatly appreciated thanks.

Further info:
Thanks rummykahn and Oguz for your suggestions.
I must confess Oguz I couldnt work out how to do what you suggest using the string approach ("copy the items of the list by only their value types (string value" )....could you elaborate with an example please. Bear in mind that the Listbox1 will contain any number from 1 to about 5 rows.
As per rummykahn's suggestion I modified my code to test that the Listbox entries were in fact there (and they were) and then I added another "debug" code line to test that myList did in fact have the entries - and they did.
I did this test by taking out the PostBackUrl="Page2.aspx"/>
Here is the code I used to prove it with :

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         for (int i = 0; i < ListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            myList.Add(ListBox1.Items[i].ToString());

      //  MessageLabel.Text = "Your listbox1 entry 0 is " + ListBox1.Items[0].ToString(); //Tested and Gets 1st row ok
        MessageLabel.Text = "Your myList entry 0 is " + myList[0]; // works also
        Session["Finallist"] = myList;
```

So I conclude that the Session["Finallist"] = myList; in page1 code does not hand over to page2 code that has:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            MessageLabel2.Text = "You are in Page2 ";
             myList = (List<string>)Session["Finallist"];
```

...and that is why my line.....
MessageLabel2.Text = "Your 1st prod " + myList[0] ;
generates the error we see.

Comment: You cannot copy controls from one page to another like that. Controls go through a life cycle from their instantiation to their rendering. Copying a control to session is also dangerous in terms of memory usage, it will cause a leak (your control holds a reference to the page. You are causing the page to be kept in memory). Instead, copy the items of the list by only their value types (string value and string key for example) and fill the list in the second page

Comment: well by watching your code, it should work prefectly.. did u checked the count of myList after getting it from session.. i think you may not have 2 elements inside the list that's y it is throwing the object reference exception.. plz check it and do let us know.. thanks

Comment: The problem was that you cant pass an array of stuff (myList) ....I had to unpack its contents into a string var (eg str1) and then do the following; Session["FinalList"] = str1 and then pick up "FinalList" on the other page - now I see the significance of Oguz comments.

Comment: But......I have used many AD environments and (stretching my memory) except for the likes of COBOL and the original Basic on DOS, all others (eg C, C++, PL/I, Pascal, Fortran etc etc ) all allowed you to pass stuff between code blocks by value or by reference (from simple var's to arrays or even whole sub-routines) ..